# Track Overlap in List Merge in Python

Tags: python, merge

I need to merge lists (make them exclusive from each other), track overlap, and evenly hold out the overlaps with several lists.  When I want to do it with two lists, I use the process below and it works great.

```
Alpha = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '6', '8']
Bravo = ['1', '2', '3', '5', '7', '9']

Overlap = set(Alpha).intersection(Bravo) # ['1','2','3']

AlphaFinal = [record for record in Alpha if record not in Overlap] # ['4','6','8']
BravoFinal = [record for record in Bravo if record not in Overlap] # ['5', '7', '9']

for Index, Value in enumerate(Overlap):
        
    if int(Index) % 2 == 0:
        AlphaFinal.append(Value) # ['2']
        BravoSkips.append(Value) # ['2']
    else:
        BravoFinal.append(Value) # ['1', '3']
        AlphaSkips.append(Value) # ['1', '3']

# AlphaFinal ends as ['4','6','8', '2']
# AlphaSkips ends as ['1', '3']

# BravoFinal ends as ['5','7','9','1','3']
# BravoSkips ends as ['2']
```

This works great for two lists, but how can I do it for 3 or 4 or more lists.   I need each of the 'Final' lists to be exclusive from all of the others, and I need the 'Skips' to be as evenly distributed as reasonably possible.

Comment: If you create a list of lists instead of individual lists, then it becomes pretty easy to generalize this.

Comment: Can you give an example input and output? If an "overlap" exists in list 3 and 4 does it matter if it then appears in the output for list 1?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is a good starting place:

```
myList = []
myList.append( [<strings>] )
myList.append( [<strings>] )
myList.append( [<strings>] )
myList.append( [<strings>] )

overlap = set(myList[0])
for lst in myList:
    overlap = overlap & set(lst)

finals = []
bumps = []
for lst in myList:
    finals.append( [rec for rec in lst if rec not in overlap] )
    bumps.append( [] )

for index, value in enumerate(overlap):
    for i in range(len(finals)):
        if i == index % len(finals):
            finals[i].append(value)
        else:
            bumps[i].append(value)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This combines the lists, but it doesn't track who is getting knocked out from which list.  I've added example behavior to my question above for clarification.

Comment: That's a pretty easy addition, isn't it?  For each index, one gets the value, the rest get bumped.  You should have been able to add that.